# STL cloning a vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

!Hi
I have a hard time trying to copy vector of pointers to Point.
I have a

```
vector<Point*> oldVector
```

and I want to copy this vector into other vector. So I used a copying constructor. I did this that way

```
vector<Point*> newVector = vector<Point*>(oldVector.begin(),oldVector.end());
```

Unfortunately I get an exception/error if I ran this function.

> vector interators incompatible

What may be the problem ??

EDIT
There must be a bigger problem with iterators, it seems that I can't use iterators at all. I wanted to add two stl vectors into each other so I used wrote sth like this

```
 vector<int> a, b;
    b.insert(b.end(), a.begin(), a.end());
```

and I get the sama exception/error during execution of this line

[image]

Comment: That's not actually your error message.  I can tell because there is a typo in it.  Can you please provide the complete error message to help people who have the same problem in the future?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That would be either

```
vector<Point*> *newVector = new vector<Point*>(oldVector.begin(),oldVector.end());
```

or

```
vector<Point*> newVector(oldVector.begin(),oldVector.end());
```

When creating objects, you only use assignment when allocating from the heap. Otherwise, you simply place the constructor argument(s) inside parentheses after your new variable name.

Alternatively, the following is much simpler:

```
vector<Point*> newVector(oldVector);
```

Comment: @Berial: Although using the copy constructor is certainly better than using the iterator version, the iterator version should work just fine.  And if it doesn't, then there must be some other problem.

Comment: @PigBen: I'd be inclined to believe that the use of the iterator version isn't the issue for two reasons: first, as @Merlyn points out in a comment above, the message about "incompatible iterators" is unlikely to be the actual error message. Second, the copy constructor is typically implemented in terms of `std::copy(oldVector.begin( ). oldVector.end( ))`, so if those don't work with the iterator version then I'd expect the copy constructor to fail too.

Comment: The "much simpler" is the one working flawlessly, yet it is harder to read :/

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<Point*> newVector = vector<Point*>(oldVector.begin(),oldVector.end());
```

Why this?

Why not this:

```
vector<Point*> newVector(oldVector.begin(),oldVector.end());
```

??.  The latter the better!

Even better is this,

```
vector<Point*> newVector(oldVector);
```

Comment: I didn't think that this makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

Because the original container is of identical type, `std::vector<Point*>`, there's no need to use the range constructor; simply use the copy constructor!

```
std::vector<Point*> newVector(oldVector);
```

But that's not the main concern here. The main issue here is that of shared pointers. Be very clear with yourself who owns the pointed-at data. Be careful of double-delete!

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
Vector<Point*> newVector(oldVector.begin(), oldVector.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work (just tested with `std::vector<int>`s). There must be some other problem. Does `Point` have a copy constructor?

Comment: copy constructors for `Point` are irrelevant - it's an array of `Point*` pointers, not `Point` objects.

Comment: I dont't think that I have to write my own copy constructor to Point class , because of the fact that this class consists only of trivial types(non reference types)

Comment: @Mac: right, just thought that might've been it because my GCC 4.5.2 doesn't error out on any of the given syntax...